# how to pass current year as default argument in php function

Tags: php, date, datetime

**I want to pass the current Year as one of the default value of a function**

I AM using

```
date("Y")
```

for current year

So it work fine when i write function in this way:

```
function MYfUNCTION($month,$year = 2013)
{
}
```

But I want to pass current year instead of 2013
but it gives me an error when i write like this

```
function MYfUNCTION($month,$year = date("Y"))
{
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Your `date` argument should be the first, and `month`, the second. The order matters when it comes to default arguments.

Comment: why don't you just check if the `$year` is set inside the function, if not set it to `date("Y")` functions can not be used for default variables

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use a function for a default argument value :

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

([extract from PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default))

You should set the default value into the function :

```
function myFunction($month, $year = null) 
{    
  if(!(bool)$year) {
    $year = date('Y');
  }
  echo $year.', '.$month;
}

myFunction('June', '2006'); // 2006, June
myFunction(3, 2010);        // 2010, 3
myFunction('July');         // 2013, July
```

Comment: Actually you should test with `is_null($year)`, not `!isset($year)`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
function MYfUNCTION($month,$year ="")
{
   if(empty($year)){
      $year = date($year); //Output: current year
   } 

   echo "Year: " . $year ." Month: " . $month;
}
```

Comment: And what will happen if someone calls the function as `MYfUNCTION($month,2012)` ?

Comment: Indeed - although I slightly prefer zessx's variation of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No direct method to pass arguments directly in the pre-defined format, you have to pass function putting the year you want to and you can make 1 more function in which you can change the year. like in php get curr year func. !! hope this can help.